# firebase admin authentication fails on server side due to missing "private_key"

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

I am hosting a `node.js` function on google firebase, and I would like to create and update user accounts on the *server side*. My service account `json` file looks like:

```
{
    "apiKey"           : ""
    "authDomain"       : ""
    "databaseURL"      : ""
    "projectId"        : ""
    "storageBucket"    : ""
    "messagingSenderId": ""
}
```

I removed the fields for reasons. When I load the credential and create an `admin` instance via:

```
import * as admin     from 'firebase-admin'    ;
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

const accountKeyPath = path.join(__dirname, '../credentials/serviceAccountKey.json')
const accountKey     = require(accountKeyPath);

const firebaseAdmin = admin.initializeApp( accountKey );
```

The `firebaseAdmin` is sufficient to `crud` a database. However it cannot create new users unless I declare it with:

```
const firebaseAdmin = admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(accountKey)
    , databaseURL: "..."
});
```

Or so it appears. When I run this I get error:

```
            throw new 

error_1.FirebaseAppError(error_1.AppErrorCodes.INVALID_CREDENTIAL, errorMessage);
            ^

Error: Certificate object must contain a string "private_key" property.
```

This is inexplicable to me because I do not know how to get a service account `json` with `private_key`. Am I suppose to create one each time I run the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is completely incorrect for the `firebase-admin` SDK. Please see the docs on how to retrieve the service account JSON file: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app

It should have the following format:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "...",
  "private_key_id": "...",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n...\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "...",
  "client_id": "...",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/example@iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Edit:

I noticed you're importing `firebase-functions` in which case you don't need to service account JSON at all. Simply call:

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk